# asyc http client - hook to capture response?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Our application makes various usages of apache HttpAsyncClient:

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client= ...
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(...);
Future<HttpResponse> f = client.execute(get,null);
HttpResponse resp=f.get()
```

I'm looking for some **hook to capture the response** just before it's passed on to the business code that invoked 'f.get()' . Inside this hook, I'll perform auditing and security sanitation. BTW Responses are short texts, so there's no problem with buffering.
Would anyone please happen to know of such hooks?

I tried HttpRequestInterceptor, but it seems to work only for **synchronous** client:

```
 // hook to audit & sanitize *synchronous* client response:
 HttpClients.custom().addInterceptorLast(new HttpRequestInterceptor(){
    public void process(HttpRequest req, HttpContext ctx) {
        HttpEntityEnclosingRequest enclosing=(HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)req;
        String body=EntityUtils.toString(enclosing.getEntity());
        // ... audit 'body'
        // ... sanitize 'body'
        enclosing.setEntity(new StringEntity(sanitizedBody))
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work for async client - I suspect the interceptor runs before response is ready; I'm looking for a hook that runs when async response **is** ready.

Thanks

Comment: It's not an option to use the FutureCallback parameter of execute as your callback?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't want to force it on the entire application (especially given existing legacy code), but thanks for the idea anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a custom `HttpAsyncResponseConsumer`. This should give you a complete control over the response message processing.

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
HttpAsyncResponseConsumer responseConsumer = new BasicAsyncResponseConsumer() {

    @Override
    protected void onResponseReceived(final HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        super.onResponseReceived(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEntityEnclosed(final HttpEntity entity, final ContentType contentType) throws IOException {
        super.onEntityEnclosed(entity, contentType);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onContentReceived(final ContentDecoder decoder, final IOControl ioctrl) throws IOException {
        super.onContentReceived(decoder, ioctrl);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse buildResult(HttpContext context) {
        return super.buildResult(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void releaseResources() {
        super.releaseResources();
    }
};
client.execute(HttpAsyncMethods.createGet("http://target/"), consumer, null);
```

PS: one can have access to message content stream from inside a protocol interceptor with blocking HttpClient but not with HttpAsyncClient